# spring boot 2.7 websecurityconfigureradapter deprecated

Tags: spring

I am trying to update my application without websecurityconfigureradapter and i need a help here.
saml authentication is failing with below code, can any one help me out here

Answer (score 2):

Please use google search. Many problems already have solutions or have been answered here or elsewhere.

Suggested search: `websecurityconfigureradapter deprecated`

I have searched it for you, and this was top of the found list: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-deprecated-websecurityconfigureradapter